# cant create arrays in while loop or if statement?

Tags: linux, arrays, bash, variables

when I try to create arrays in my script I get errors.
`id[1]=string2;` would generate error `id[1]=string2: not found`

I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that im in a if statement or while loop since the use `[]`? I'm running a VM so attached is a pic of the script thus far the array at top `a[1]=string;` generates no errors but the one in the logic `id[1]=string2;` does.

[image]

Comment: Your screen shot doesn't show a shebang line. Are you sure this gets executed by bash, not sh?

Comment: Anyway, you should post actual code, not screen shots.

Comment: @tripleee it was the shebang. I was under the impression it was optional but I guess not. Thanks.

Comment: @tripleee: you should make your comment an answer, such that the OP can flag your answer as accepted. Or the question should be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting as an answer so this question can be marked as resolved:

Your script is being executed by `sh`, not `bash`. Add a correct shebang line as the first line of the script file:

```
#!/bin/bash
```